# TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined on NodeJs

Tags: node.js, undefined

I don't know what to do to solve this problem

- $ `rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules <-- you need both`
- $ `npm install`
- insert a stable version of node ( 10.16.0 )

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "supervisor -i node_modules index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.0",
    "bot-brother": "^2.1.5",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "helmet": "^3.8.1",
    "joi": "^10.6.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "pg": "^7.6.1",
    "raven": "^2.2.1",
    "supervisor": "^0.12.0"
  }
}
```

when i try to `npm start` i receive this error

[image]
the only package that i installed separately is supervisor ( npm install supervisor), but just because it's needed for the script npm start.

If you need other files i will be happy to post it :)

i don't know what to do, how can i try to solve it ?

***Update***

As Requested this is `bot.js`

```
const bb = require('bot-brother');
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require('path');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);


const bot = bb({
  key: process.env.BOT_KEY,
  sessionManager: bb.sessionManager.redis({ port: process.env.REDIS_PORT, host: process.env.REDIS_HOST }),
  polling: { interval: 5, timeout: 65 }
});

//middlewares
bot.use('before', bb.middlewares.typing());

const actions = {}

//load all actions wrappers
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname + "/actions")
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const name = file.replace(".js", "")
    actions[name] = require(path.join(__dirname + "/actions", file));
  });

//load all actions
Object.keys(actions).forEach(name => actions[name](bot))

module.exports = bot
```

Comment: can you post the `bot.js` file, context around line 7.

Comment: @Aritra Chakraborty  as requested, thanks for the interest

I don't know if could help you, but i-m using redis and postGre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see `process.env.BOT_KEY` declared anywhere. So basically the `Key` is undefined.

To set the `BOT_KEY` environment variable, you should start node with

```
BOT_KEY='something' node <filename>
// or 
export the BOT_KEY 
// or 
use `dotenv` and set the config in the config file.
```

To handle the case, handle it by:

```
const bot = bb({
  ....
  key: process.env.BOT_KEY || "some secret key",
  ....
});
```